# No tests error in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently using gradle 0.13.2 to build my android project. Whenever I attempt to execute the gradle command: `./gradlew :app:build connectedCheck` I keep getting a "No Tests" found error, even though I have tests. I ran the command with the `--debug` option and It seems from the output that the reason this is failing is because two of the modules in my project don't have any tests, which is causing the whole build process to fail.

The really strange part about this is that this only started occurring recently. I assume this is due to a new gradle version but I can't be sure since my IDE (Android Studio) upgrades gradle  automatically for me.

How can I go back to getting my gradle command to pass even though there are modules without any tests in my project?

---

**Update:**

I did a bit of research and found that this change in functionality to Gradle is intentional and can be followed here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76249&q=no%20tests&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

A good solution would now be to find a way to designate modules in which we don't want this check to execute in.

Comment: Could you paste the output?

Comment: @FiferSheep I did a bit of research and it actually turns out this is not a bug, but a feature of Gradle now! It was put in Gradle since version 13.1. For now I have downgraded my Gradle version. I will also update my answer to reflect this. It seems that the ultimate solution will be to have some way of designating modules in which you do not want tests to run in.